# How can div wrapper grow with img size?

Tags: php, html, css

How can div wrapper grow with img size?

```
<div style="width:900px;">
    <div style="width:100%;"> 
      <div>some text......</div>
      <img src="<?php echo $imageSrc; ?>"/> 
      <div>some text......</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocks take up the whole of their parent's width by default (minus margin, border and padding widths), so the `100%` doesn't really do anything.

What you seem to be looking for is ‘shink-to-fit’ behaviour, where the parent's width is determined by the child. To get this you have to use something other than normal static positioning, one of:

- `float: left`, perhaps followed by a `clear`;
- `position: absolute`;
- `display: inline-block` (clean but historically less well-supported);
- tables.

in each case with no explicit `width`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width from the wrapper; that way it'll be stretched to whatever width its content requires. The 100% width now equals the width of the div's parent element.

Comment: also when i remove i still have the problem, because its inside other div.

Comment: Block elements do not shrink-to-fit horizontally, only vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `padding:1px` to the div can do the job as well, in case you are fine with the 1px padding.